# How to dynamically change the backgroud css on react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. I have got an application where I have to implement a functionality where a user should be able to switch between a normal site & color blind site (basically site is offered for these 2 kinds of users). Basically, we'll be changing the background of the react app (i.e. black for color blind people & normal/white for a normal user). To implement these features, the site will be having 2 buttons (1 button for color blind people & 1 button for normal people). Once a user clicks on the "color-blind" button, the site background color will become black & when the user clicks on the normal button, the site will have a default/normal look.

I don't know how to proceed with this in react, so looking for some good help here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to implement a button with actions behind them? Do you know how to style your components? Which packages do you use for styling?

Answer (score 1):

The [react context docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) include examples specifically about theming.

If you didn't want to go that route you could toggle a css class at the root of the page or the root of the app and have your css rules adapt accordingly.

The example below isn't react specific, but could easily be implemented in react.

```js
function toggleTheme () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: bisque;
  color: tomato;
}

body.dark {
  background: tomato;
  color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">hello</div>
<button onclick="toggleTheme()">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

probably if you are using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) in react [themes](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming) concept will help you in this case. styled-components has full theming support by exporting a  wrapper component. This component provides a theme to all React components underneath itself via the context API.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can use `<link>` and `<style>` elements anywhere in your HTML?

You can put a component anywhere with code line this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={ this.state.color_blind ? "color_blind.css" : "style.css"/>
```

The code will apply to the whole page regardless of where in the hierarchy it is placed.